# Ruby on Rails: How to have multiple submit buttons going to different methods (maybe with with_action?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-submit

So..

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save', :name => 'save' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Save to Library', :name => 'library' %>
```

then in my controller:

```
with_action do |a|
    a.save do

    end

    a.library do

    end
end
```

the problem is that only one of the actions is getting invoked... the same one for both submit_tags... 
any idea why?

or how I can get two buttons to submit a form to two different methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The submit button name attribute is passed to the controller as params[:commit].
So in your case:

```
if params[:commit] == "save"
end
```

Comment: I did a puts params,
and there isn't a :commit key in the params hash... =\

Comment: What does the params hash contain?

Comment: When I use :name there is no :commit.
wehn i don't use :name, the :commit is the text of the button

Comment: Then use the name instead of `:commit`.

Comment: Works for me. Been looking all over for the answer to this trick. Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916316/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-when-clicking-submit-button-in-simple-form-view-in#new-answer if you want to pass a specific param to the controller depending on which button was clicked.