# How to have two submit buttons within a form_for in Rails submit to different actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How can one have two submit buttons within one form_for method submit to different actions?

I first saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332449/rails-multi-submit-buttons-in-one-form) and followed a link in one of the answers to this (rather old) [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form)  Towards the end of this Railscast, Ryan Bates suggests using the submit_to_remote method to submit the form to that different action.  I can't find this submit_to_remote method in the documenation (I'm using Rails 3.1).  Is there still a way to have different submit buttons submit to different actions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Widgets = window.Widgets || { };
 Widgets.orders = {
    initialize      : function( ) {
        jQuery('#sumbit1').live('click', function(){
          Widgets.orders.submitOne();
        });
        jQuery('#sumbit2').live('click', function(){
          Widgets.orders.submitTwo();
        });
    },

    submitOne :function(num) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url: "/widgets/orders" ,
          data: jQuery('#order_form').serialize(),
          success: function(htmlText){
            if (htmlText.status > 399) {
              alert('OH NO!!!  Something went wrong!!');
            } else {
              jQuery('#orders').html(htmlText);
            }
          },
          dataType: 'html'
        });
    },
    submitTwo :function(num) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url: "/blah/orders" ,
          data: jQuery('#order_form').serialize(),
          success: function(htmlText){
            if (htmlText.status > 399) {
              alert('OH NO!!!  Something went wrong!!');
            } else {
              jQuery('#orders').html(htmlText);
            }
          },
          dataType: 'html'
        });
    }

// Start it up
jQuery(function() {
  Widgets.orders.initialize();
});

};
```