# Submit same form to different actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, http, strong-parameters

Depending on which `submit` button a user selects, (`Cat` and `Dog` in this case), I'd like to submit the form to the right controller action using the right http verb.

In this case, there is one text input. If the user presses `Cat` I'd like to `POST` to `Cats#create` and if `Dog` to `PUT` to `Dogs#update`.

How would I build the form?

[image]

### Edit

Using the [`formaction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536941/2909897) attribute I'm able to `PUT` to `Dogs#update`

```
<%= form_for(cat) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Cat" %>
    <%= f.submit "Dog", formaction: dog_path(Dog.first) %>
    <%#= f.submit "Cat", name: 'route_to[cat]' %>
    <%#= f.submit "Dog", name: 'route_to[dog]' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is I want to `POST` to `Dogs#create`, is this possible with `formaction`?

### Edit

There is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form?autoplay=true) about building the logic the controller based on the name of the button pressed. But I want to put the logic about which HTTP verb, controller, and action in the submit button itself. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you try making the different requests using AJAX instead of traditional HTML form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case creating a `Cat` and updating a `Dog` were related enough that it makes sense to handle both in the `CatsController` with a [case statement](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) and use a `:name` attribute on on the `submit` button.

For example:

app/views/cats/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag(cats_path, multipart: true, role: "form") do %>
  <%= button_tag 'Cat', name: 'route_to[cat]'%>
  <%= button_tag 'Dog', name: 'route_to[dog]' %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/cats_controller.rb:

```
def create
  case route_to params
  when :cat
    # create a cat
  when :dog
    # update a dog
  end
end
.
.
.
private

  def route_to params
    params[:route_to].keys.first.to_sym
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the simple form with some fields and submit button. And then create similar form but with hidden fields which will be filled when user fills the first form's fields (use javascript for that) and visible submit button. So user fills the first form visible fields, javascript code copies the values to the second form's corresponding hidden fields. User has two submits to click on. For `@items` you could have hidden fields too and manually set fields' values within `@items` values.

Or an **alternative solution** which works in my project and could fit your needs probably. To use it you need to introduce some `condition` which will "decide" what controller and action should be used.

Your view:

```
<% if condition %>
  <%= form_tag controller: "foos", action: "create", method: :post %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: {button_name: "Foo"} %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_tag controller: "bars", action: "update", method: :put do %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: {button_name: "Bar"} %>
<% end %>
```

Your `_form` partial:

```
<%# Your form and @items fields %>    
<%= submit_tag button_name %>
```

That solution gives you one single form and submit button for this form. What form it will be (for `Foos` or `Bars`) depends on `condition.`