# Rails Form Button Showing Value not Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with two `submit` buttons, each sending different parameters.  The first should read "Save for Later" and the other should say "Submit for Consideration".

However, they are currently displaying the value of the parameter being sent, not the text.  I've tried the following options, all with the same result:

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Save for Later", name: "application_status_id", value: 2, class: "btn btn-light" %>
<%= f.button :submit, "Submit for Consideration", name: "application_status_id", value: 3, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Which was the same result as:

```
<%= f.submit "Save for Later", name: "application_status_id", value: 2, class: "btn btn-light" %>
<%= f.submit "Submit for Consideration", name: "application_status_id", value: 3, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

And I also tried using a `do`/`end` structure, but got the same result.

How do I get these to show the text instead of the values?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332449/rails-multi-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `f.submit` since it tries to set the text based on the model state https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit.

I wouldn't use `submit_tag` either since inputs with type submit uses the "value" value as the text. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

Use two button tags instead with type "submit":

```
<%= button_tag "Save for Later", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 2, class: "btn btn-light" %>
<%= button_tag "Submit for Consideration", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 3, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag

Comment: Worked perfectly and great background knowledge!  Thank you!