# Is there a way to pass params when clicking submit button in simple_form view in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

In simple_form view, the submit button is like this:

```
<%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>
```

We are trying to pass a params `subaction` when clicking the `Save` button. The `params[:subaction]` should have value of 'update' after clicking the button. Here is what we tried in view but it did not work:

```
<%= f.button :submit, 'Save', :subaction => 'update' %>
```

Is there a way to pass a value in `params[:subaction]` when clicking the `Save` button?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use name and value option.

```
   <%= f.button  :submit , name: "subaction",value: "update"%>
```

In your controller you will get params[:subaction] with the value "update"

Comment: Tried <%= f.button :submit, name: 'subaction', value: for_which, :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %> and for_which is a string and the params[:subaction] is nil. It did not work.

Comment: I am using this code and working. Please see the log while submitting the form whether params are sending or not.

Comment: just tried this and it's working for what i need, but it's changing the submit button's text to the value of "value:" - is there a way to keep the name/value giving the controller the info it needs while still having a name of my choosing for the submit button?

ie: button text should be "next student" but it's "2"

`<%= f.submit "Next student", :class => 'big_button round unselectable', name: "student_group_id", value: @student_group.id %>`

Comment: actually i got it working with a hidden_field_tag instead, +1 though, thanks!

Comment: what if you want to pass more than 1 param?

Comment: This worked for me `redirect_to users_url(1, params: {a: :b}, subdomain: 'bob')`

Answer (score 25):

as dax points out,

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, 'update') %>
<%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>
```

This will provide the string value 'update' to the routed controller action via the hidden field.  It can then be retrieved by the controller with

```
params[:subaction]
```

Comment: the main thing, that you `hidden_field_tag` must be without `f`, which refers to model.

Answer (score 18):

By specifying `f.button :button, type: 'submit'`, we can use the `name` and `value` attributes as follows to submit using a single param. Notably, the value submitted (e.g., 'cake') may be different from the button text (e.g., 'The Best Cake').

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.button :button, 'The Best Cake', type: 'submit', name: 'dessert_choice', value: 'cake' %>
<%= f.button :button, 'The Best Pie', type: 'submit', name: 'dessert_choice', value: 'pie' %>
```

**Controller**

```
def controller_action
  dessert_choice = params[:dessert_choice] # 'cake' or 'pie'
end
```

This approach avoids the need for hidden inputs as @dax mentioned in the comment above.

Tested on Simple Form 3.3.1 with Rails 4.2.