# Can I pass params from button submit in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do something simple: in my Rails view, I have a text input that I want to capture and append to the params. I [found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916316/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-when-clicking-submit-button-in-simple-form-view-in), but I want to know if I can do it inline without updating the controller.

First, in the view, I have a form input and a Rails link. These work independently right now for testing, but I can pass the username as a param on button click:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
 </form>    
    <%= button_to 'Call Action', points_path(username: @current_user.last.username), method: :post %>
```

I want to remove the `@current_user.last.username` and instead pass what the user has typed in the input as a param.

Is there a way to do this without a subaction, as outlined above, in the controller (either through a helper or using Javascript with my Rails link)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to submit a form, let's do it in Rails way,

```
<%= form_for :points, points_path do |f|  %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the action you can access the `name` param by `params[:points][:name]`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, I think the logic of your answer makes sense, and I should do it the Rails way. When I make those updates and load the view, I am getting an error for `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`. I am wondering if my `:points` is an issue, since I am not actually sending data to the database -- I am just trying to append it to the params. Will report back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Attach a javascript click event to the button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615917/3012550) that prevents the default behaviour.

   - In your click event, fetch the value of the input element and append it to the url `var go_to = "/path/to/action?param_name=" + input_value`.
2. Then redirect to that url.

It looks like you're using the post method, so you could check out [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) with instructions on how to post from JavaScript without using ajax - in a nutshell you make a form on the fly and submit it.

## Edit

@RSB's got it right - that's the rails way to do it. If you insist on using a button and a standalone input instead of a form, you can do it the way I described... but I think you're better off following @RSB's advice.