# simple_form_for - multiple submit buttons with different params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of checkboxes within a form, which has two buttons. I'm trying to pass in separate paramaters to the buttons as described here:

[Is there a way to pass params when clicking submit button in simple_form view in rails 3.2.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916316/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-when-clicking-submit-button-in-simple-form-view-in#new-answer)

But it's not passing in the parameters. My code is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for :pupils, url: edit_multiple_school_group_pupils_path(school, group) do |f| %>
  ...
  ...
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Change Levels', name: 'editing', value: 'levels' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Move to A Class', name: 'editing', value: 'classes' %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried various other methods, and have seen a few posts about giving the buttons separate ids and calling params[:commit], however no commit params are sent.

Any help is greatly appareciated.

EDIT:

The HTML output of the form buttons are:

```
<input type="submit" name="editing" value="levels" class="btn" />
<input type="submit" name="editing" value="classes" class="btn" />
```

Rails console log:

```
Started POST "/school/2/classes/3/pupils/edit_multiple" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-08 17:08:58 +0100
Processing by Schools::Admin::PupilsController#edit_multiple as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0ncVG1+MfuS13ystwdUe/vEzF30f1iHS/F0u0DDflOXKnkw8hcUhv/n2eJZuZHOA4gZxuITahMFbyTdG/B5cEQ==", "pupil_ids"=>["134", "129"], "school_id"=>"2", "group_id"=>"3"}
```

Comment: Can you post the log the log that appears when you click on submit?

Comment: Sure, I've updated it with the params being submitted and the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue. I have two submit buttons within a simple_form_for. When I post the form to the controller the :commit params are missing.

My solution is to use jquery to capture the click event for the submits that writes the submit value to a hidden input. I can then use that input value to control logic in the controller.