# Rails simple_form: passing params on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, simple-form

I'd like to pass custom params when user submits a form. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916316/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-when-clicking-submit-button-in-simple-form-view-in?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I still didn't get it to work.

These are my params on the form page: `{"email"=>"user@example.com", "controller"=>"devise/passwords", "action"=>"new"}`

Here's my form :

```
%h2 Forgot your password?
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f|   =
f.error_notification   
.form-inputs
  = f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, input_html: { value: params[:email] }   
.form-actions
  = f.button :button, 'Submit', type: 'submit', name: 'email', value: params[:email]
```

Was this behaviour depreciated at some point or am I doing something wrong?
I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.

Comment: `simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name, email: params[:email]), html: {...`

Comment: @Vasilisa this doesn't seem to change anything: I still have the param available on the form page but not after submit.

Comment: Did you remove name and value from button?

Comment: @Vasilisa I didn't before (wasn't really clear from your comment) but tried it now - no change.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed - you already have input for email. Why do you want to pass it one more time? And what do you have now in params after submitting form?

Comment: just add a hidden field to your form, you can retrieve this param from the form params in the controller.

Comment: @Vasilisa I don't want to pass it one more time, I'd just like to keep it in params after redirection. Right now after submit my params are `{"controller"=>"devise/sessions", "action"=>"new"}`

Comment: @Maxence I tried with a hidden field but that also doesn't let me pass the param to the page after redirection on submit.

Comment: Well this is the purpose of instance variable to pass data from controller to the view...?

Comment: `{"controller"=>"devise/sessions", "action"=>"new"}` isn't equal `password_path(resource_name)`, I suppose. It should be devise/passwords, action create. Something goes totally wrong. Do you have any authorization restrictions?

Comment: You are in `devise/sessions/new` when you click "Forgot password" and get taken to `devise/passwords/new`, and the original idea was to redirect back to login after an email is submitted (so you'd be back at `sessions/new`), with the email already filled in from params.

Comment: Your form goes to devise/passwords/create, which redirects you to devise/session/new. So you need to change Devise::PasswordsController, not the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your after password reset path so that you can pass a param :

```
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name) 
  my_path(email: resource.email)
end
```

This should work if your route to your successful password reset page is a `collection` path. If it is a `member` path, then just add resource like :

```
 def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name) 
   my_path(resource, email: resource.email)
 end
```

But I dont recommend using a `member` because it could leak data.

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You describe in comments the situation when some params were passed to the controller and then happens some redirect. So, redirect do fire some new action that doesn't know what parameters was passed to prev action.

You must pass that parameters handly. For example

```
redirect_to resource_path(resource, email: params[:email])
```

But, if you want to show the same view as before use render instead redirect.

Comment: I'm using devise passwords_controller and the `after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for` method. I'd like to redirect to a static page saying something like "Password reset instructions were sent to #{params[:email]}". I tried with `def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    password_reset_path(email: params[:email])
  end` but  that also doesn't seem to pass the param.

Comment: Devise? @Maxence already given the correct answer how to do that for Devise.

Comment: Also if you want not display email in URL, you can save email in the user session and then put that into view as variable @email = session['email']